# Using jQuery cycle plugin for slideshow with overflow visible area for slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle

So, here is how the slideshow looks.

`a[b]cde`

In this example, **b** is the visible part of the slideshow. When **b** is visible, you can't see **a,c,d**, or **e**.

Is it possible that when **b** is showing, that you can see a preview, or overflow, of the right quarter of **a** and left quarter of **c**? These previews would essentially be next and previous buttons that have a translucent background.

I don't want for just the one active slide to show, I want to be able to see a left quarter of the before slide and right quarter of the after slide just before they come in or after they leave, respectively.

I don't know what part of the cycle plugin I need to rewrite or code in order to do this. Is it too hard or difficult to accomplish with the cycle plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The cycle plugin gives numerous callbacks, such as `before` and `after` which can probably be used to to add the behavior you described. They are all outlined here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

The `before` callback is called before a transition happens and is passed `currSlideElement` and `nextSlideElement` as parameters.

Using these parameters, you can get a reference to the image that will appear next, or has just appeared and do anything you wish with it. This may mean cloning it and displaying it next to the slideshow.

I'm confident that some combination of `before` and `after` callbacks will make this behavior possible.

Comment: hmm ok, i see those. but i'm not sure how to call those functions. I tried adding them but it broke the slider. i am too new to jQuery to really understand how to do this without hand-holding sadly. :(

Comment: In that case this may be a pretty ambitious project. There may be another slideshow which handles this without customization. Your question may be too broad as it would (in my view) cover a wide range of programming topics to complete this feature.